# Linux Device Drivers filp_open() error: EFAULT

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm working with Linux device drivers, `filp_open()` is not opening the file and I get EFAULT as error.. What could be the reason and what changes do I have to make my code for it to work?

```
int keyboard_event_handler(struct notifier_block *nblock, unsigned long code, void *_param)
{
    char keybuf[12] = {0};
    struct keyboard_notifier_param *param = _param;
 
    if (!(param->down)) return NOTIFY_OK;
 
    keycode_to_string(param->value, param->shift, keybuf, 12);
 
    if (strlen(keybuf) < 1) return NOTIFY_OK;
    
    printk(KERN_INFO "Keylog: %s", keybuf);
    struct file* filp = NULL;
    char buf[] = "2";
    int bytes_written;
    int err;
    filp = filp_open("/sys/class/leds/dell::kbd_backlight", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644);

    if (IS_ERR(filp)) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error opening file:");
        return -1;
    }
    if(strcmp(keybuf,"z") == 0)
    {
        bytes_written = kernel_write(filp, (void*)buf, sizeof(buf), &filp->f_pos);
        if (bytes_written < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error writing to file:\n");
        } else {
        printk(KERN_INFO "%d bytes written to file\n", bytes_written);
        }
    }
    err = filp_close(filp, NULL);
    if (err){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Error closing file:\n");
    }
    return NOTIFY_OK;
}
```

Comment: are you sure this is the right way to access the backlight in the kernel?

Comment: I am not really sure, but i have seen codes changing the brightness of screen this way, so i guess it's fine. Even I'm unable to open that brightness file, getting g the same error :(

Comment: as far as I understand it, it is very much not fine to open file paths from the kernel. Your driver should somehow connect directly to the backlight driver instead. (No, I'm not sure how to do that. There is probably something like an LED object, instead of a file object)

Comment: How do you ever deduce that error code is EFAULT? You print the error message without the error code: `printk(KERN_ALERT "Error opening file:");`.

Comment: I have printed error message and when modifying my code again I just didn't write it..that's it

Comment: Letting aside whether this is the proper way to control a LED object that way, I am pretty sure that all entries inside `/sys/class/leds` are directories or symbolic links to directories, so you may want to try to open `/sys/class/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/brightness` instead or at least explore the sysfs structure in order to verify that you try to open the correct file.